# How to iterate over all these possibilities?

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume we have a python list

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I define the sum as the following,

sum: is the total sum of single entries (different index) from each of the sublists.

This sounds complex so I will give an example,

for the above list, 1 + 5 + 9 is one of the sums because 1 is from the first sublist and 5 is from the second sublist and 9 is from the 3rd sublist and they all have different positions in their corresponding sublist.

so i can't have `1 + 4 + 7` because 1,4 & 7 are first entries in their sublists.

I can't have `1 + 5 + 8` because 5 & 8 are both second entries in their list and so on

for example, 
and I want to find the highest sum of the total of individual entries of each of the sublist !!

How can I iterate over all these possible sums and then get the  highest out of all these sums.

For the above list, we have 3^3=27 different sums.

And is there an efficient way to do it with python ?

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing you'd *not* want to just iterate though and check all the permutations.

Comment: but if I didn't iterate through all, how would I get the highest sum ? @AdamSmith

Comment: This is pathfinding. A* maybe? The naive implementation uses `itertools.product` though

Comment: Is this pathfinding? It seems different to me - for instance if you're at the node "5" in the example you can't necessarily go to 7 8 or 9 depending on where you came from. You'd need an exponentially large graph to represent all the possibles "paths", wouldn't you?

Comment: @James right, but that's just the DFS that the naive implementation does.

Comment: Why 27 sums, not 6?

Comment: let say i=0 ( sum = list[i][i] + list[i+1][i+1] + list[i+2][i+2] ) . you might want to make it more generic. This is only the first part though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann 

You are absolutely right  !!

There are just six possibilites because of the different position requirements !

Is it easier to solve now ?

Comment: @alkabary The number of possibilities is still n!, so that still makes it a very time-intensive algorithm on an non-trivially sized data sets. The answer given seems to be your best bet

Comment: Is the array always *square* - same number of rows and columns?

Comment: @wwii, no not necessarily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic problem that can be solved using [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). There is an implementation in sklearn:

```
from sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_ import linear_assignment
import numpy as np

M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

M = np.array(M)  #convert to numpy array

result = linear_assignment(M)

answer = sum(M[cell[0]][cell[1]] for cell in result)
```

Iterate over all possible sums is a bad idea (O(N!)). The algorithm above must run in O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

The naive implementation uses `itertools.product` to produce all possible pairings, then filters out the ones that won't work due to indexing issues.

```
from itertools import product

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

with_indices = [ [(idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate(sublst)] for sublst in lst]
# [ [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)],
#   [(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6)],
#   [(0, 7), (1, 8), (2, 9)] ]

total_product = product(*with_indices)

filtered_product = [
    [p[0][1], p[1][1], p[2][1]] for p in total_product if
        len(set([p[0][0], p[1][0], p[2][0]])) == 3]
# p[0][1], p[1][1], p[2][1] refers to original values
# p[0][0], p[1][0], p[2][0] refers to original indices
# asserting the length of the set of indices is 3 ensures that all are unique.

# [[1, 5, 9],
#  [1, 6, 8],
#  [2, 4, 9],
#  [2, 6, 7],
#  [3, 4, 8],
#  [3, 5, 7]]

result = max(filtered_product, key=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about **execution efficiency**, but for code writing efficiency you can consider:

```
for k in itertools.permutations(lst):
    print(sum([j[i] for i, j in enumerate(k)]))
```

Will only work for square list as in OP example.